# is-check or a cast that involves the non-generic part of the type

Tags: kotlin

I got a few question when I was reading the Kotlin reference:

In "Type erasure and generic type checks", it mention:

**When you already have the type arguments of an instance checked statically (at compile
time), you can make an is-check or a cast that involves the non-generic part of the type. Note
that angle brackets are omitted in this case**

and they gave a example:

```
fun handleStrings(list: List<String>) {
    if (list is ArrayList) {
        // `list` is smart-cast to `ArrayList<String>`
    }
}
```

Q1: I test myself

```
val a = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3)
val b = listOf(1, 2, 3)
println(a is List)   //error, should use List<*>
println(b is MutableList)   //can compile
```

I don't understand why they got different result.

Q2: I found that I can't use smart cast from List to ArrayList

```
println(listOf(1, 2, 3) is ArrayList)  //false
println(listOf(1, 2, 3) is MutableList)  //true
```

As I remember, listOf() is implement by ArrayList in Kotlin, it calls `asList`, which return a ArrayList, in Arrays.java.
So, why can't listOf() smart cast to ArrayList?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A1: In the first case, you cast from subclass to superclass. It does not make any sense, since instance of subclass can always be used as an instance of superclass without casting:

```java
val a: MutableList<Int> = mutableList(1, 2, 3)
val b: List<Int> = a
```

So the Kotlin compiler does not implement generic smart cast for casting upstairs and uses default rules of casting which require star projection.

In the second case you cast from superclass to subclass, so it works as intended.

A2: There are two different `ArrayList` classes. Try to run this code:

```java
println(listOf(1, 2, 3)::class)
println(ArrayList<String>()::class)
```

It prints:

```
class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
class java.util.ArrayList
```

`listOf` returns a nested class `Arrays.ArrayList`, not `ArrayList` you usually work with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's helpful!

Comment: Also, the exact return type of `listOf()` is not specified in the documentation, probably because it may change in future: it could return special objects for empty or very small lists, for example, or they may come up with a higher-performing and/or genuinely immutable implementation.  So you shouldn't make any assumptions about the exact type, or rely on it in any way.